# Is there a difference between .submit and .click when using $.get in jquery?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I have this really strange problem: The **first function works** and picks up information as it should, the **second does works** , the **third function does not work**. (I commented them each out while testing) I tried for a little with `$.post` but being new to jquery tried to make it simpler and simple get some information instead. Does the  `.click(function()` work differently to  `.submit(function()` ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#mybutton').click(function(){
    $.get("<?echo base_url();?>index.php/example",function(data,status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
    });

    $('#emailform').submit(function(){
    alert("UNDERSTOOD");
    });

    //This does not work when at all, including when commenting the above function above out.   
    $('#emailform').submit(function(){
    $.get("<?echo base_url();?>index.php/example",function(data,status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: what are you using to submit the form? type=submit or type=button?

Comment: `<form id="emailform"  action="" >` and `<input type="Submit" value="Submit">`

Comment: okay! then you have to prevent the default action of submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send an ajax request on submit event, you should prevent the default action of the event:

```
$('#emailform').submit(function(event){
   event.preventDefault()
   $.get("<?echo base_url();?>index.php/example",function(data,status){
      alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
   });
});
```

Comment: excellent, thank you :D wanted to use this for some testing purposes. i understand that normally it would be used differently.